# Добавить класс к элементу

Tags: php, jquery

помогите решить вопрос с списком
есть список с вложенными ссылками

```
    <h3><a href="/kalendar">Календарь</a></h3>
    <p >
        <a href="#">Первый календарь</a><br>
        <a href="#">Второй календарь</a>
    </p>

    <h3><a href="/visitors_list">Cписок гостей</a></h3>
    <p>
        <a href="#">Первый список</a><br>
        <a href="#">Второй список</a>
    </p>


$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".spldv2 h3:first").addClass("spl2btact");
    $(".spldv2 p:not(:first)").hide();

    $(".spldv2 h3").on('click', function(e){
        if(e.target.tagName != 'A'){
            $(this).next("p").slideToggle("slow")
            .siblings("p:visible").slideUp("slow");
            $(this).toggleClass("spl2btact");
            $(this).siblings("h3").removeClass("spl2btact");
        };
     });

 });
```

Все работает корректно,первый список развернутый при загрузке страницы.
Теперь как бы оптимизировать работу скрипта чтоб при открытии страницы /kalendar или /visitors_list был развернутый соответствующий список ?
Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: решите сей вопрос на уровне верстки в пхп, а не в jquery

Answer (score 0):

Проверяйте нужный url через селектор: `a[href="' + window.location.pathname + '"]'`

Учитывая вашу верстку, после селекта нужного a, потребуется применить .parent() для работы с h3 привычным вам способом.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('.spldv2 h3 a[href="' + window.location.pathname + '"]')
    .parent().next("p").slideDown("slow")
    .siblings("p:visible").slideUp("slow");

    $('.spldv2 h3 a[href="' + window.location.pathname + '"]')
    .parent().addClass("spl2btact"); 

    $('.spldv2 h3 a[href="' + window.location.pathname + '"]')
    .parent().siblings("h3").removeClass("spl2btact");


    $(".spldv2 h3").on('click', function(e){
        if(e.target.tagName != 'A'){
            $(this).next("p").slideToggle("slow")
            .siblings("p:visible").slideUp("slow");
            $(this).toggleClass("spl2btact");
            $(this).siblings("h3").removeClass("spl2btact");
        };
     });
 });
```

Ссылка на fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/54mzty0w/
(нажмите run и посмотрите).

Вот здесь хороший ответ для задачи проверки текущего url с href ссылки:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4443276/jquery-if-link-page-url

Comment: Заменил на ваш код и к сожалению не работает...

Comment: Писал с телефона. Доберусь до пк кину ссылку на jsfiddle

Comment: Спасибо буду ждать

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/54mzty0w/

Переписал без использования фильтра. Вашу задачу будет решать как положено.

Comment: Протестировал Ваш код,при обновлении страницы все списки развернутны

Comment: Надо правильные значения url подставлять. В примере на jsfiddle посмотрите. Скрипт запускается сначала при загрузке jsfiddle с одним url, а затем при нажатии run с другим. Проверьте через alert правильные для вашего случая и кода значения window.location.pathname.